# Use Kerberos for Authentication with Scalding/Cascading

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, cascading, accumulo, scalding

I have some jobs that use **Scalding** to ingest **Avro** files into **Accumulo**.   The current system uses **username/password** for **authentication**.  The new system uses **Kerberos** for authentication.

Currently the code uses a class **com.talk3.cascading.accumulo.AccumuloConnector.AccumuloConnectorBuilder**.  The "connector" returned is ultimately used to generate the **AccumuloSource**.  The AccumuloConnectorBuilder, which I have had trouble finding the source for, only appears to permit username/password authentication.

I thought if I could find the source it would be a perfect starting point to modify and add in Kerberos authentication.

Otherwise, I may have to write my own class from scratch unless I can find a better idea.

Comment: I can't even find the project which AccumuloConnectorBuilder comes from. It does not appear to be a part of https://github.com/airawat/cascading.accumulo ; Perhaps talk3 has chosen to keep their current version proprietary?

Comment: It is just strange that all remnants of older versions appear to be gone, but then maybe the source was never released.